# NextJS Credentials Custom Sign in redirects to default form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js

I am trying to create a web app with authentication using NextJS default auth middleware but the app is redirecting me to the default NextJS form component on the URL `/api/auth/signin?error=CredentialsSignin`.

I have created a custom login page on `src/pages/account/login.js` but I am handling the login process with the default [signIn](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#signin) NextJS method:

```js
const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);

    const formData = new FormData(e.target);
    const options = {
        email: formData.get('email'),
        password: formData.get('password')
    };

    if (redirect) {
        options.callbackUrl = redirect;
    }

    try {
        await signIn('credentials', options);
    } catch (e) {
        setError(e.message);
        setLoading(false);
    }
    
};
```

According to the [Next Auth documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages#sign-in-page), it's enough to add the `signIn` value to the `pages` property at `src/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js` file:

```js
export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            pages:{
                signIn: '/account/login',
            },
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "Juan@mail.uy" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "********" },
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                const { email, password } = credentials;

                try {
                    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
                    if (!user) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
                    if (!isPasswordValid) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    return user;
                } catch (error) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

        })
    ],
}
```

Despite all of this, after logging in with some error I am redirected to the default NextJS form and I don't what I am doing wrong. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `options` you should have `redirect:false`

```
const options = {
    email: formData.get('email'),
    password: formData.get('password'),
    redirect:false
};
```

now you can handle the navigation on the client side

```
 const signInResult= await signIn('credentials', options);

 if(signInResult.error){
       // navigate here 
    } else {
      // if not error, go to home page
       window.location.href="/"
}
```